# How to set environment variable of export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1?

Tags: node.js, express, opencv, environment-variables, replit

I am attempting to set an environment variable for opencv4nodejs, but all that is told in the documentation is to do

export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1

for linux OS(I am using repl.it to run my program, and replit runs on linux OS).

The issue is I don't know how to do this. I know I have to use secrets to set the env variable, but I  have no idea what to set the "key" and "value" to for the Env var.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEx4b.png)

Here is what I have, but my best guess is to set OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD for the key and 1 to the value, though I either am not calling that right in index.js or I set the wrong values. My question is, which is my error here and how do I fix it.

Thanks.

EDIT: I made a mistake reading the documentation. Thought it ended there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66mze.png)

Thanks to user 'TBA' the first issue was figured out. The next, is, how does an environment variable point to a folder? I'm assuming the value would then be a path such as /folderOfStuff, but do I manually add a folder called "opencv2"

Comment: The key should be `OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD` (and not `export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1`) and the value should be 1 (and not empty)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to use this as well? Still getting the same error when I const mySecret that in index.js. Im not sure how to use it.

Comment: Not error of the thing itself but of it not being used

Comment: Are you using this variable in your code or only during compile\build time?

Comment: Oh my bad I made some mistakes, your thing worked, I just didn;t see more steps. I edited the question